# PHP, check folder for files that begin with a particular string

Tags: php

I am trying to search a directory with PHP, I want to check a directory that begins with something like: `folder_2` for example.

In this `folder_2` directory I need to return a count of all files that `begin` with the string: `image_5_`

Is there any simple way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: [`echo count(glob('folder_2/image_5_*'));`](http://php.net/manual/function.glob.php) probably

Comment: @Yoshi Very simple, yet effective. Thanks alot!

Comment: Wow, that's cooler than **[preg_grep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)**.

Comment: @Yoshi Works fine, but it always returns `1` even if there are no matches. But anything else works fine, is there a reason for this?

Comment: Found out returns `FALSE` with no matches, which `count()` returns `1`

Answer (score 0):

Use `scandir` to List files and directories inside the specified path
and then compare each directory name using `substr`  (make it return the first part of each string)